# JQuery UI controls not working after jquery.js loads after jquery.ui.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm having an issue working with JQuery UI. I'm working on a product (widgets) which will be deployed in a page where multiple other widgets are also installed.

I've referred jquery.js first and jquery.ui.js after that in my widget and I'm using some jquery UI controls like calendar, tooltip etc.

But when it is deployed in a common page I see that other widgets are also loading jquery.min.js. But they are getting loaded after my jquery ui script file is loaded. Because of this none of my jQuery UI controls are loading properly since jQuery UI objects are getting overridden.

So how can I make sure that my jQuery UI controls work in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put your own plug-in and your jquery.ui.js after those widgets and don't load jQuery again? This sounds like a really weird situations because normally, a widget should not load jQuery on its own. If you are allowed to modify those widgets, maybe go in and remove the part that loads jQuery.

Comment: I'm working in a product-like environment. Users can put my widget anywhere they like. Even they can put it in a fresh page where no other widgets are there. They can put it an existing page where some widgets are available. It should work, no matter what.

Comment: Do you have permission to modify those  widgets?

Comment: I can check if jQuery/jQuery UI is already loaded and load my jQuery. But I can't expect the same diligent code with other widgets.

Comment: No. My app is a product. They can put it anywhere as I mentioned. I'll never know where they will put it.